# Android Studio - ¿Por qué mi View Pager se ve como si tuviese 0dp?

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpager, height, scroll-view

**Descripción:**

Estoy jugando un poco con los diseños y me encontré, como dice el título, con el error de altura del view pager. Estoy intentando lograr que **View Pager** ocupe (en altura) desde su posición en el tope hasta la parte inferior del todo. En resumen, quiero que este tenga un **layout_height** como si fuese **match_constraints**

**Adjunto foto de como se ve mi View pager**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código XML de la actividad que se ve en la foto:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F8F6F5"
android:contentDescription="Ayuda">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_foto"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/perfil"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Tomás Menniti"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#252525"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_foto"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_editar_perfil"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arimo_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:text="@string/editar_perfil"
            android:textColor="#4e342e"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_nombre"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_barra0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_editar_perfil"
            android:background="#C5C5C5"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_barra0">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabss_perfil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F8F6F5"
                android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#a1887f"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#C5C5C5"
            android:layout_below="@id/bar_layout"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_perfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_below="@id/txt_barra1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

el problema es el NestedScroll, copie tu codigo e hice unos cambios, por ejemplo si quieres crear un linea para separa contenido, no ncesita ser un TextView, puedes usar View

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F8F6F5">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_foto"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:src="@drawable/perfil" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/img_foto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Tomás Menniti"
        android:textColor="#252525"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_editar_perfil"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_nombre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="hskdfhgskdhfkg"
        android:textColor="#4e342e" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_barra0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_editar_perfil"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_barra0">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabss_perfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F8F6F5"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#a1887f"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar_layout"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_perfil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_barra1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Hola francisco y gracias por comentar. Primero quiero preguntarte en que cambia el hecho de reemplazar mis "barras" de tipo Text View por "barras" de tipo View. Otra cosa a comentarte es que me BORRASTE mi Nested Scroll View, el cual quiero conservar para que afecte al contenido de dentro del View Pager. Agradecería muchisimo que puedas resolverlo pero conservando el nested.

Comment: TextView o View no hay mucha diferencia en el layout, pero si uno ve un TextView es porque espera que se muestre un texto, revisa bien donde quieres que aparezca el nestedscroll, si es solo para el ViewPager entonces puedes crear algo como linearlayout -> nestedscroll -> ViewPager

Comment: Lo que quiero es que el nested scroll afecte a toda la actividad y también al view pager. Tal y como se ve en el archivo XML que adjunté. Pero, repito, no estoy pudiendo lograrlo porque mi diseño hace que el view pager tennga 0dp por alguna razón. Tenés idea de como solucionarlo? Otra consulta: El hecho de  usar "View" en lugar de "Text View", me va a hacer diferencia en algo?